# Execute part of a script from R console or terminal

Tags: r

Is there a way to only run only part of a script in `R`? For instance, give the following example saved in `Myfile.R`

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
plot(x, y)
plot(x, y*y)
```

`source('Myfile.R')` from within `R` will execute everything (the same does `Rscript 'Myfile.R'` in the terminal) but is there a way to run, say, the first three lines of the script only?

Comment: This is why we use IDEs such as RStudio.

Comment: OK, but there are cases where this is impractical and you want to use the terminal instead (in my case a VM on a HPC cluster, possibly without graphical interface)